# Validate x-editable using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, x-editable

I am using http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/ and wish to validate an input using Ajax.  For testing, I created the following script https://jsfiddle.net/m698gxgj/1/.

My Ajax request is asynchronous so the validate callback returns I believe `undefined`, and therefore it doesn't result in the input failing validation.

I "could" change my Ajax request to be synchronous, but everything I read (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/1032531) indicates that is not a good idea.

How is this accomplished?

```
<p>Name</p><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="name"></a>

$('#name').editable({
    type: 'text',
    title: 'Name',
    url: '/echo/json/',
    pk: 123,
    validate: function (value) {
        if (value == 'bob') {
            return 'bob is not allowed';
        } else {
            $.post('/echo/html/', {
                html: 'false',
                delay: .5
            }, function (result) {
                if (result == 'false') {
                    console.log('remote error');
                    return 'remote error';
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `validate` option is only to be used for client side validation, so the `if (value == 'bob')` bit is alright, but you shouldn't fire the ajax post in the `else` block.

You should make the `url` option do the ajax post, then you can leverage the `success` and `error` options to handle async callback properly.

For example:

```
$('#name').editable({
    type: 'text',
    title: 'Name',
    url: function () {
        return $.post('/echo/json/', {
            json: 'false',
            delay: .5
        });
    },
    pk: 123,
    validate: function (value) {
        if (value == 'bob') {
            return 'bob is not allowed';
        }
    },
    success: function (response) {
        if(response === false) {
            console.log('remote error from success');
            return 'remote error';
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log('remote error from fail');
        return 'remote error';
    }
});
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x0bdavn7/

Comment: Thanks Starscream1984.  Given my current script, ideally I could somehow use the `validate` callback, but will probably end up doing exactly as you show.

Comment: I have the user entering an account number and then I want to get the account name from the server and ask the user if it is the right name, before allowing x-editable to update the field. So I need the ajax inside the validate() function and I need the validate() function to wait for the ajax response. Any ideas?

Comment: I think my original answer is relevant for your question too - `validate()` will only work for client-side validation, it will not wait for a response. You can have your `success` callback ask the user if the username from the response is correct.